# running example-sixlowpan.cc in NS3

Tags: c++, debugging, ns-3

I am receicing the following error when trying to run the example-sixlowpan.cc file in NS3, i have placed both the example-sixlowpan.cc and example-ping-lr-wpan.cc files within a folder named 6lowpan within the scratch folder of NS3.

after running "./waf --run example-sixlowpan" i receive the following error:

Waf: Leaving directory `/repos/ns-allinone-3.25/ns-3.25/build'
Build failed
 -> task in '6lowpan' failed (exit status 1): 
    {task 140117242282192: cxxprogram example-ping-lr-wpan.cc.3.o,example-sixlowpan.cc.3.o -> 6lowpan}
['/usr/bin/g++', '-pthread', '-pthread', 'scratch/6lowpan/example-ping-lr-wpan.cc.3.o', 'scratch/6lowpan/example-sixlowpan.cc.3.o', '-o', '/repos/ns-allinone-3.25/ns-3.25/build/scratch/6lowpan/6lowpan', '-Wl,-Bstatic', '-Wl,-Bdynamic', '-Wl,--no-as-needed', '-L.', '-lns3.25-test-debug', '-lns3.25-lr-wpan-debug', '-lns3.25-netanim-debug', '-lns3.25-lte-debug', '-lns3.25-spectrum-debug', '-lns3.25-antenna-debug', '-lns3.25-aodv-debug', '-lns3.25-applications-debug', '-lns3.25-csma-layout-debug', '-lns3.25-dsdv-debug', '-lns3.25-dsr-debug', '-lns3.25-flow-monitor-debug', '-lns3.25-internet-apps-debug', '-lns3.25-mesh-debug', '-lns3.25-wimax-debug', '-lns3.25-nix-vector-routing-debug', '-lns3.25-olsr-debug', '-lns3.25-point-to-point-layout-debug', '-lns3.25-sixlowpan-debug', '-lns3.25-tap-bridge-debug', '-lns3.25-visualizer-debug', '-lns3.25-wave-debug', '-lns3.25-internet-debug', '-lns3.25-bridge-debug', '-lns3.25-point-to-point-debug', '-lns3.25-mpi-debug', '-lns3.25-traffic-control-debug', '-lns3.25-wifi-debug', '-lns3.25-buildings-debug', '-lns3.25-propagation-debug', '-lns3.25-uan-debug', '-lns3.25-mobility-debug', '-lns3.25-energy-debug', '-lns3.25-config-store-debug', '-lns3.25-csma-debug', '-lns3.25-fd-net-device-debug', '-lns3.25-virtual-net-device-debug', '-lns3.25-topology-read-debug', '-lns3.25-network-debug', '-lns3.25-stats-debug', '-lns3.25-core-debug', '-lrt', '-lgsl', '-lgslcblas', '-lm', '-lsqlite3', '-lgtk-x11-2.0', '-lgdk-x11-2.0', '-latk-1.0', '-lgio-2.0', '-lpangoft2-1.0', '-lpangocairo-1.0', '-lgdk_pixbuf-2.0', '-lcairo', '-lpango-1.0', '-lfontconfig', '-lgobject-2.0', '-lglib-2.0', '-lfreetype', '-lxml2']

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the following command

```
 ./waf --run scratch/6lowpan/example-sixlowpan
```

or place the example-sixlowpan.cc file in scratch folder.